# What would be the most efficient way to generate a Discord-like username discriminator?

Tags: mysql

What's the most efficient way to find a random, yet unique, username discriminator; similar to how Discord and other services have begun using?

For instance, 1000 users may have the username JohnSmith but they'll all have distinct discriminators. So one user may be JohnSmith`#3482` while another is JohnSmith`#4782`. When a new user registers (or changes their username) to JohnSmith, what would be the most efficient way to find an available discriminator?

For this example, let's assume a discriminator is numeric and between 0000-9999, and always 4 digits.

One method would be to fetch the discriminators of all users with the name JohnSmith and loop over them with an incremental counter until it found a number not occupied. However, this would be loading a lot of rows and wouldn't result in a truly random number.

Another option would be the same as the first, but generate a random number and check it against the results until an opening is found. This, however, could result in a very long process if only 1 opening exists, and would require tracking already-tested numbers to know when all options have been exhausted.

A third option, a hybrid of the two, would be to find all unused discriminators, persist them to an array, then randomly select one from the array.

Is there an easier way or more efficient manner than these?

Answer (score 0):

Fetch all would be the slowest and most expensive operation. This kind of application should already be optimized to lookup a user by username for many reasons such as login. So the best way is to generate a random number and lookup if it exists.

If you are expecting a lot of collisions then it could get expensive as well. For that I would suggest increasing the total range for the discriminator so the collisions are less. 100 users => 1000->9999, 1000 users => 10000-99999.

You can try some other hacky ways, like pick the last JohnSmith, add a small random number to it mod the total number, and then check collision. That should give a similar random distribution. But having a large range is the best option.

For something similar would be how git determines the short SHA: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Revision-Selection

Comment: I'm actually looking to do something similar to what Discord, Xbox, and various other popular gaming platforms are doing. So the discriminators will be assigned randomly, are prone to changes, and won't follow any predictable pattern. I also wish to limit it to 4 numerical digits for simplicity in memorizing it. That said, SHA hashing techniques, using modulus, or other "hacky ways" wouldn't be very practical.